# How to check for time every minutes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

Let's say I want to build a Reminder App. It allow user to set a time which will remind them to do their work. For example: 24th March 07:03 PM.

The easiest way I can think of is to use `whenever` gem and set a crontab every minutes and check if there is any reminder needs to be fire.

But I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this. Or if now users want to set a reminder in seconds, what can I do? For example: 24th March 07:03:33 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this and be accurate to seconds is with a delayed background job.

For example [resque_scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler)

When a user creates a reminder you enqueue a job at specific time.

```
 reminder = Reminder.last
 # assuming reminder has a column reminder_at and there is 
 # a job that processes these reminders, ProcessReminderJob
 Resque.enqueue_at(reminder.remind_at, ProcessReminderJob, reminder.id)
```